# CodeIgniter controller won't load a helper

Tags: php, codeigniter

I created a helper in CodeIgniter 3 which I called `asset_helper.php`

[image]

and this is the controller I use to call this helper:

```
<?php

class Index extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('asset');
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('nav');
        $this->load->view('title');
        $this->load->view('stat1');
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }

}
```

but when I access to the controller I get this message:

> Unable to load the requested file: helpers/asset_helper.php

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried [auto loading](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/autoloader.html) the helper?

Comment: @bmla yes I tried it but I had the same problem

Comment: Just see if `Asset_helper.php` file name with upper case. But do not think that would be issue.

Comment: You should also check that web server has permissions to access that file.

Answer (score 0):

Load like this

```
$this->load->helper('asset_helper');
```

If you use like this `$this->load->helper('asset');` it will never works.B Bcz there is no file call `asset`